# Should prop definitions be as detailed as possible even for a single developer?

Tags: vue.js

I'm reading the Style Guide of Vue and trying to understand the prop styling part. It's is written in the  [Stle Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-definitions-essential):

> Detailed prop definitions have two advantages:
>
> - They document the API of the component so that it’s easy to see how
>   the component is meant to be used.
> - In development, Vue will warn you
>   if a component is ever provided incorrectly formatted props, helping
>   you catch potential sources of error.

However, let us say I'm nearly done with my developing of a page and never used detailed props.

I have at least 50 vue components. Should I still update every component's prop to a detailed one?

I'm the owner and developer of a page. No other than me is going to read my code. I don't see any new advantages for updating these.

What do you think?

Comment: The advantages as outlined are useful even if you're the only developer. In particular, the type checking that prop definitions enable are most helpful IMO. Whether or not you should update is probably a matter of personal opinion and really depends on how much time you're willing to invest now to prevent potential bugs later.

Comment: Future you is not the same person as you today.  Be kind to future you, and write comments and prop names that are just detailed enough to help future you figure out what the heck the you of today was even thinking when he wrote that terrible code.

Comment: @LeoBartkus loved it!